# I do not understand -printf script

Tags: linux, bash, script

I have taken over the responsibility of RHEL5 scripting and I've not had any training in this platform or bash scripting.  There's a script that has multiple pieces to it and I will ask only about the second piece but also show you the first, as I think it will help with my question below.

The first part of the script shows the output of users on a particular server:

```
cut -d : -f 1 /etc/passwd
```

The output will look something like:

```
root
bin
joe
rob
other...
```

The second script requires me to fill in each of the accounts listed from the above script and run.  From what I can gather, and from my search on the man pages and other web searches, it goes out and finds the group owner of a file or directory and obviously sorts and picks out just unique records but not really sure - so that's my question, what does the below script really do?  (The funny thing is, is that if I plug in each name from the output above, I'll sometimes receive a "cannot find username blah, blah, blah" message.)

> `find`*`username`*`-printf %G | sort | uniq`

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the `find` man page, you'll find a description of the `-printf` option:

```
   -printf format
          True; print format on the standard output, interpreting `\' escapes
          and `%' directives...
```

If you look further down the man page, you'll find the documentation for `%G`:

```
          %G     File's numeric group ID.
```

So, this finds all files contained in a directory called `username` (in your example) and prints out the numeric group id that owns them.  This gets piped to `sort`, which will sort them lexically.  The results of the `sort` get piped to `uniq`, which will remove duplicate entries.

So this produces a list of all the unique group ids that own files in a certain directory tree.

As written this won't do exactly that, because there are no delimiters.  If you have files owned by group `200` and `100`, the output would look like:

```
100200
```

...which means that `sort` will only see a single line and won't do anything.

One could add a newline to the format string to fix that:

```
find username -printf '%G\n' | ...
```